# File was not uploaded. error while uploading the product

Tags: .htaccess, magento, magento-1.9

I am new to Magento, while uploading product Image, it gives error all the time "File was not uploaded".

Log not able to understand the info:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien   .php on line 108
2015-10-17T04:09:42+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cookieParams in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 109
2015-10-17T04:09:42+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cookieParams  in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 118
2015-10-17T04:09:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /home/laschin1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 118
```

All permission are correct
modified htaccess file
Media catalog/category is having correct permission
Please help me

Comment: Do you have correct permissions for media and cache folders ? also you can see the issues by enabling the logs from admin side.

Comment: Media permission: 777   media/catelog/product/cache permission : 777   please guide.

Comment: Did you check by enable the logs from admin ?

Comment: @anupam.unique Check app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php file for any modification and replace with default magento unmodified file and then check.

Comment: Dear Mahomood, i have enabled the log, but there is no exception log, attached the system log: which i something as below.  if you dont mind then share any id ( anupam.unique@gmail.com), i can share you credentials to look.  Thanks.

Comment: @Muk : I have replaced that file still issue.